# How to import primary secret key from backup into GnuPG?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I've seen ["Re-import secret primary key in GnuPG"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100807/re-import-secret-primary-key-in-gnupg) which is pretty much the issue I'm seeing, but I haven't had any luck with GnuPG 1.4.20 (from GPGTools) or GnuPG 2.1.

Even if I delete my entire `~/.gnupg` and try the import again, I can't seem to get the primary key secret to import. I'm assuming no keys are being merged when starting from scratch, so I don't understand why this wouldn't work even on GnuPG 1.4.

My backup file does contain the private key:

```
➜  ~ gpg --list-packets master-secret-key.gpg
:secret key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1459961571, expires 0
    skey[0]: [4096 bits]
    skey[1]: [17 bits]
    gnu-dummy S2K, algo: 3, SHA1 protection, hash: 2
    protect IV:
    keyid: DBDE1E0253A3B420
...
```

Starting from scratch with an empty `~/.gnupg`:

```
➜  ~ gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import master-secret-key.gpg public-key.asc
gpg: key 53A3B420: secret key imported
gpg: key 53A3B420: public key "Rodrigo López Dato <rodrigo@auth0.com>" imported
gpg: key 7C4C5564: public key "Rodrigo López Dato <rolodato@rolodato.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2  (RSA: 2)
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:   secret keys imported: 1
➜  ~ gpg -K
/Users/rolodato/.gnupg/secring.gpg
----------------------------------
sec#  4096R/53A3B420 2016-04-06
uid                  Rodrigo López Dato <rolodato@rolodato.com>
uid                  Rodrigo López Dato <rodrigo@auth0.com>
ssb   2048R/00E7B480 2016-04-06
ssb   2048R/7D9F38D2 2016-04-06
```

`sec#` means the private master key wasn't imported, why is that?

FWIW, I need the master key to generate a revocation certificate and to eventually renew my subkeys once they expire. If there's a way to do this from the backup directly without needing to import it, that would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you're trying to import does *not* contain the actual private key, as indicated by this line in the output of `gpg --list-packets`:

```
gnu-dummy S2K, algo: 3, SHA1 protection, hash: 2
```

The special "dummy" S2K algorithm is applied when GnuPG actually exported a secret key stub to still enable using secret subkeys, but having an offline primary key (on another computer, a disconnected thumb drive, an OpenPGP smartcard, ...). This key stub is also what you observe in the `--list-secret-keys`/`-K` output:

```
sec#  4096R/53A3B420 2016-04-06
```